# Amazon EC2 - access application through specific Port.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

I'm developing a node app on Amazon EC2. Everything is working fine and I can deploy to both Heroku and Github, but I'm at a loss when it comes to viewing the actual application running on port 5000 (or whichever one I'm using for the app).

I tried running `ifconfig`and it gave me some public / private dns addresses. Using these as the URL failed.

Do I need to create an Elastic IP Address? Is there some simple way to view my app before deploying?

Answer (score 6):

In order to access a specific port on your instance you need to open that port up in the firewall. I suggest creating a group specifically for your Node.js server to ensure that the port is not accessible on other instances you might have.

1. Go to EC2 > Security Groups
2. Either select an existing Security Group or create one
3. Make sure that SSH is allowed for inbound 0.0.0.0/0
4. Create a new inbound Custom TCP Rule for port 5000 allowing 0.0.0.0/0 [image: Security Group]
5. Click Add Rule
6. Click Apply Rule Changes

In order to get your Public DNS for your instance, click EC2 > Instances, then click on your instance and scroll down in the info pane until you see this:

[image: Public DNS]

In this example the Public DNS is `ec2-23-20-36-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, and thus if you want the IP it is `23.20.36.91`. You can then connect on either `23.20.36.91:5000` or `ec2-23-20-36-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000`.

That should do it. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: i run ifconfig to get my ip address, add :5000 (After following your suggestions) but it still cannot find the server

Comment: If you run ifconfig from your instance it will more than likely report your internal IP which can only be reached from other instances within the AWS cloud (if they are allowed by security groups). In order to find the IP of your instance, look at the public DNS and use that instead. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS you need to ope port through Firewall (Security Groups).
It is not necessary to have Elastic IP, but you can, just remember not to hold IP non-attached (as it will be then charged), but for attached IP - it is totally fine.

Go to:
`EC2 > Security Groups > 'select your group' > 'tab Inbound' > Add IP > Apply`

Comment: 'Add IP' is not one of the Security Group options (see: http://i.imgur.com/sayGKOS.png)

Comment: Type your Port your self just in field below and ignore presets you just viewing (in screenshot).